# Index of Automorphism groups of graphs with colour class of bounded size.

Tags: group-theory, graphing-functions, algebraic-graph-theory

I am trying to understand group theoretic algorithms for graph isomorphism problem. In page number 64 and 65 of [this](http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/cmh/distribution/books0/chapter3.pdf) book chapter, the author has bounded the index of the concerned automorphism groups (lemma 2 and 3). I really did not understand how does this statement - "if $\pi$ and $\psi \in G^{(r+j-1)}$ such that $\pi\psi^{(-1)}$ stabilizes every vertex in $C_j$ , then
$\pi$ and $\psi$ lie in the same right coset of $G^{(r+j)}$"- leads to the bound in lemma 3. I found the argument in proof of lemma 2 even more confusing.
Is there some standard techniques to bound the number of cosets being employed here?

Here the vertex set of graph is partitioned into $s$ colour classes each with maximum size $k$, which are to be preserved by the isomorphism. They create $\binom{s}{2} +1$ induced graphs, each having vertex set $V$, the vertex set of original graph, and starting from empty set edge set are build inductively, where at each step, edges having one vertex  in class $i$ and other in class $j$ are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick look at Lemma 3. I haven't studied the notation at all, but I presume that the elements of $G^{(r+j-1)}$ permute the vertices in the set $C_j$? Since $|C_j| \le k$, there are at most $k!$ possible permutations that could be induced by elements of $G^{(r+j-1)}$. But if two such elements $\pi$ and $\psi$ induce the same permutation, then $\pi \psi^{-1}$ stabilizes all vertices in $C_j$, and hence $\pi$ and $\psi$ lie in the same right coset of $G^{(r+j)}$. So there can be at most $k!$ such right cosets, which gives the bound on the index. The argument in Lemma 2 is similar.

Comment: G(r+j) fixes all the elements of C1 through Cj pointwise. So G(r+j-1) permutes elements of Cj through Cs, thus there may be more than k! permutations.I understand that if ab^{-1} stabilized Cj pointwise then they belong to same right coset, but how does that lead to the bound.

Comment: Because the number of cosets is at most the number of permutations of $C_j$, which is at most $k!$, because $|C_j| \le k$.

Comment: The arguments doest not carry over exactly to lemma 2, since groups defined in lemma 2 are automorphism groups (hence set wise stabilizer of colour class) while in lemma 3 are point-wise stabiliser. I understood proof of lemma 3, but i am confused in proof of lemma 2 because even there point-wise stabilizer of $C_h \cup C_i$ are considered though the associated group is only set-wise stabilizer.

Comment: The permutations in $G^{(j)}$ all permute the set $C_i$ and they all permute $C_h$. Since $|C_i| \le k$ and $|C_h| \le k$, the total number of permutations of $C_h \cup C_i$ that can be induced in this way by elements of $G^{j)}$ is at most $(k!)^2$. So the argument is essentially the same as in Lemma 3.